# Load a Twitter Bootstrap Popover on Page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following BootStrap popover:

```
<a href='#' id='example' rel='popover' data-placement='left' data-content='Its so simple to create a tooltop for my website!' data-original-title='Twitter Bootstrap Popover'>HEY</a>
```

And I want to show it when the page loads, so I added

```
$('#example').popover('show')
```

to a function as follows at the end of the document:

```
<script>
$(function ()
{ $("#example").popover(show);
});
</script>
```

but nothing happened.

On page load I get nothing. However when I run `$('#example').popover('show')` in the console I get the popover working. How can I make the popover be shown when the page has loaded?

Answer (score 12):

I found this way to be convenient:

You can trigger the 'show' and set options in one fell swoop:

```
$('#elementToPointAt').popover({
   'placement':'bottom',
   'content':'Look at me!'
}).popover('show');
```

Comment: +1.. grt, it works..
`$('#elementToPointAt').popover({
   'placement':'bottom',
   'content':'Look at me!'
}).popover('show').on('click',function(){
    $(this).popover('hide');
});`

Comment: If your popover needs to be dissmissable by any click on the dom, follow the instructions in the bootstrap docs v.5.2 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/popovers/#dismiss-on-next-click, and show the popover on load by adding this:   $('#your-onload-popover').focus();

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the quotes for `show`. This works:

```
$(function () { 
  $("#example").popover('show');
});
```

Full example would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <a href='#' id='example' rel='popover' data-placement='right' data-content='Its so simple to create a tooltop for my website!' data-original-title='Twitter Bootstrap Popover'>HEY</a>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() { 
        $("#example").popover('show');
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hm ... it works fine for me in Chrome. Do you use Developer Tools or Firebug? They instantly tell you that without the quotes it does not work. `Uncaught ReferenceError: show is not defined `

Comment: yep, when i run in console i get the same thing, i add the quotes - all good but on page load it will not trigger

Comment: did you include jquery before your own script?

Comment: yes everything loads, then this runs last. Jquery running fine through out the rest of the page

Comment: I edited my answer and gave a full example that works for me in Chrome and FF. Make you've got the paths to the css and js files right. This must work :)

Comment: Hmm i am running this in rails and its the last section of JS to load but still nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Run it after window is loaded like so:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $("#example").popover('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#example").popover({'placement':'bottom'}).popover('show');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

window.setTimeout("$('#example').popover('show')",1000);

}
```

It works for me. Try it out.

Answer (score -1):

Trigger the click event of that anchor tag using jQuery like

```
$('[id$='example' ]').trigger("click");
```