# Popover on page load

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I add elements to the page dynamically, so when I need a popover I use something like this:

```
$('body').popover({
    selector: '[data-toggle=\"popover\"]',
    trigger: 'click',
    placement: 'right'
});
```

I need to add another element that needs to have the popover loaded when the element is loaded and should stay next to it on the page as long as the element is present. So, I've added element and attempted the following:

```
$('body').popover({
    selector: '.myPopover',
    placement: 'right'
});

<div class="popover myPopover right">...</div>
```

I think I need some sort of trigger, kind of like I did on click, but am not sure what to use for onload...

PS Just noticed that the docs of bootstrap have example that is loaded on page open. Can't figure out how they do that. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16044207/1004312